# Batch file writting when a prompt comes up

Tags: batch-file

I would like to know if its possible to have a batch file type for me.

Example:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>date
The current date is: Thu 11/14/2019
Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy) :: I would like the script to enter the date format I want ::
```

Using **`echo`** not working and I'm also not sure what to search to find my answer.

Comment: Your question is unclear. what do you mean by the format you want?

Comment: `echo 31-12-22|date`. `date` expects the date in a given format. You can't use another format.

Comment: Are you simply wanting to set the date from the command line via a batch file?

Comment: Why not just use `date 11-14-2019`?

Comment: In fact, you should be able to enter `date 09.13.2017`, `date 09-13-17` or `date 9/13/17`, despite it stipulating a format, it appears the order is all it needs. See more about the `date` command by opening the Command Prompt window and entering `date /?`, or by visiting [Microsoft's help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/date).

Comment: `date` does not change the date format, so the *format you want* makes no sense. The expected format is based on the settings made in Control Panel or Settings, and the prompt in `Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yyyy)` is based on that setting. If you want the *format you want*, then change the setting in Control Panel to the one you want.

Comment: Oh okay, thought that using the date command would change the format of the date.